# Drupal 7 and WordPress 3.8 on a Windows production server?

Tags: linux, windows, apache, iis, drupal

I have not had a Windows production server in years. According to recent stats, few people are running WAMP production servers and even far less have WIMP. The majority of Web developers that I know use WAMP for development purposes only (e.g., I currently have WampServer on my local desktop).

That said, I work in a .Net shop and so, although I am tasked to produce a website for the company in Drupal or WordPress (or both), I am told that the server *has* to have a Windows operating system in order to take advantage of in-house knowledge for supporting the server. Windows and Drupal/WordPress (i.e., PHP and MySQL) are the only given technical criteria; I can dictate what kind of Windows server it will be, and any necessary configurations.

I would like to hear from anyone who has experience running either a WAMP or WIMP production server. I am *not* a systems administrator, but the sys admins here know nothing about open source technologies. So I have a few questions:

1. **What are the required changes or roadblocks one can expect with the latest versions of Drupal (7) and/or WordPress (3.8) running on Windows instead of Linux?** For example, I'm aware that file paths are going to be different.
2. **How can you get the server to run as fast as a Linux server?** To my knowledge, I'm guessing... Disable automatic updates and unexpected reboots, increase RAM, additional CPU, more recent version of Windows? Can I run it without the GUI? My main concern is that I don't want the server to take five minutes to reboot!
3. **IIS or Apache or third option?** Obviously, IIS is native to Windows. However, I prefer Apache. It seems easier to configure properly, IMHO. You can have clean URLs. I'm also afraid that the Drupal / WordPress ecosystem is developed with Apache in mind; I haven't tested either with IIS.
4. **For Windows, what other performance optimizations and configurations (e.g., page caching) do you recommend?** FastCGI and Wincache? Memcache? Again, I'm not a sys admin, so I may be using these terms incorrectly.
5. **Is WampServer fine for use in a production environment?** Or can it be configured so that it is OK for production? I really like it as it is easy-to-use and I currently use it for local development.
6. **Any particular version of Windows?** Can you run it without the GUI?

***I realize that this question has been asked before, elsewhere, but I can only find information from over three years ago. If you do point me to other online resources, please cite information from within the past 18 months. :)***

Thanks for the help and happy holidays!

Jason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What are the required changes or roadblocks one can expect with the latest versions of Drupal (7) and/or WordPress (3.8) running on Windows instead of Linux?

None. Drupal, Wordpress, etc, run on PHP. PHP uses the same codebase cross-platform, and is tested so before any release.

Whenever issues come up, they usually get reported and fixed quickly because there are many many PHP installs on Windows; and I believe some of the devs of PHP run it primarily on Windows.

> How can you get the server to run as fast as a Linux server?

Install only the minimal needed Windows Server setup (no IIS, MSQL, SMTP, DNS Server, etc). Don't run any 3rd-party firewall, anti-virus, and anti-malware applications.

Tune Apache and MySQL settings for your resources.

Aside from that, use a caching layer if you are really interested in performance: Apache's mod_mem_cache on Windows using Apache's native thread-based MPM is quite powerful, and will beat any PHP opcode cache by entire folds/factors.

PHP's opcode caches tend to be hit and miss with regards to stability and script compatibility.

> IIS or Apache or third option?

Use Apache.

Just like PHP, it's codebase is cross-platform. It has no issues on Windows that I've seen.

> For Windows, what other performance optimizations and configurations (e.g., page caching) do you recommend?

Apache - adjust the number of Workers to your concurrent load.

MySQL - adjust MyISAM and InnoDB buffers and buffer logs to your available RAM.

If you are running native firewall or anti-virus s/w, make sure to exclude Apache's and MySQL's binary paths, and the WAMP's Temp and Database folders.

> Is WampServer fine for use in a production environment?

The only WAMP that I know of that's officially stated as being for production is [Wamp-Developer Pro](http://www.devside.net/server/webdeveloper). You'd have to take a look at [WampServer](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) and [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html) pages to see what they state. *WampDeveloper is not free (but does come with support).

> Any particular version of Windows?

Windows Server 2012 would be good... As long as it's not XP or Server 2003. If it's a client version, then Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with rightstuff in the belief that Drupal 7 or WordPress 3.8 work just fine on Windows, it's how I've run stuff (Drupal 6 and WordPress < 3.8) for years.

(My caveat being I'm not hosting a considerable number of high traffic sites, though the hosting isn't trivial just the same. Also, I'm talking Windows Server 2008 R2 as of late.)

I wouldn't rule out IIS (since MS have put a lot of work into PHP for IIS recently -- http://php.iis.net/), though without knowing specifics it's hard to say what will apply for you. It sounds like Apache is more comfortable from your end.

As far as keeping performance high, there are caching options in Drupal, and modules/plugins for both Drupal and WordPress, alongside things like the Windows Cache Extension for PHP, etc.

I'd also like to add that a 5 minute reboot isn't likely on decent hardware (whether it's Windows or Linux), but performance tuning specific services should smooth out any rough spots.

(I'd avoid running anything you don't need, but make sure you cover your bases re: what you do need. Web, FTP, Email, etc.)

If you're going to be running multiple sites (via IIS), make sure to look at the Advanced Settings for Application Pools to keep memory use, etc. in check. IIS should auto-generate these (unless you're custom spinning virtual directory setups) and they'll give you greater control over performance and (if you need it) permissions via Application Pool Identities (http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities).